# Cordova not able to build with cordova-plugin-local-notifications

Tags: android, cordova, android-notifications, cordova-plugins

I have added notification plugin using this command:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications.git
```

However when I build the App, it fails with below error.

```
> cordova build android --release

ANDROID_HOME=E:\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:support-v4:+.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.119 secs
Error: Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,"E:\PhoneGap\MyApp\platforms\android\gradlew 
cdvBuildRelease -b E:\PhoneGap\MyApp\platforms\android\build.gradle 
-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking cue from @Del I installed the following extra's and the build was successful. I am using Cordova 6.1.1

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have the similar issue, and I achieved a workarround. After creating the platform, open the platform/android folder with android Studio

In the project left tab, left click in android, and select "Open Module Settings"

Go to "Dependencies" Tab, click "+" and "Library Dependency"

Select the "support v4" and click "OK"

Now you can build it.

Also, it could be achieved adding

```
<framework src="com.android.support:support-v4:+" />
```

To your config.xml, but it didn't worked for me

Also you have more info here:

https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/issues/492

Maybe this helps you.

Please, post your results

Comment: Thanks. I actually don't use Android Studio. Just Notepad++ for coding and command line for building. So fist option is out. I tried the second option also, but that also gave the same error. Is there any specific place to put this statement in? Or it can be anywhere in the config.xml?